# fixing my header image on specific static page

Tags: html, css, image, header, blogger

hello I have a little problem after adding a widget script "Recent Post by Label on Static Pages" on the static page my header image has changed slightly but only on this page where I have add the script, for other pages it is good no problem the header image look great can you give me a solution and thank you

the problem page : https://mon-blogger-code.blogspot.com/p/tutoriel-blogger.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1ewM.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b359H.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post images ... they are less searchable and your question will be useless once the link target gets removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `height: 90` from the `#header-blog` style rule. It makes the height fixed, and removes part of your header image. If you can't change the style rule, add a new one that says:

```
#header-blog {
    height: auto!important;
}
```